# What was the currency in use in Palestine shortly before and during WWI?

Tags: world-war-one, palestine, currency, ottoman-empire

Wikipedia lists the following Ottoman currencies: Akçe, Para, Kuruş, Lira, Sultanî, but I would like to now which were prevalent in actual use (or, rather, uses). Also, such a variety suggests that perhaps different geographical areas saw the use of different currencies. Another aspect that occurs to me is: how prevalent was the use of European currencies, in comparison to Ottoman currency(ies)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From 1516 to 1917 it was Ottoman money,
named gold liran asmali.
To be specific, from 1807 to 1918 they used a different Ottoman currency named 
tamashlik,onlic,[sikwin](http://i66.servimg.com/u/f66/14/96/76/47/008211.jpg). In 1914 when the Ottomans lost in WWI, [French Liran gold](http://ejabat.google.com/ejabat/thread?tid=45ff40e9027ecd0c) became prevalent. In 1917/11/23 the British announced that Egyptian money was legal, as well as Ottoman, and any money from allies.

References (not in English, or a Latin alphabet):

- http://ejabat.google.com/ejabat/thread?tid=45ff40e9027ecd0c
- http://abukhadra.ba7r.org/t1852-topic

Comment: +1 format is a bit messed up, but the content looks nice...

Comment: @mdnth: 1222 sounds weird - what might have been the original meaning?

Comment: 1222 is a date, 1222-1918 is an era of ruling

Comment: @mdnth: But the Ottomans only appear in 1299, according to wikipedia...

Comment: i used islamic dates , i ll edit it,1222 hijri=1807 DC

Comment: If I were you, I would only list the second reference. Because it itself has credible refernces from known encyclopedias. But good answer and the second reference has all the history of coins used in Palastine for those interested.

Comment: The Ottoman Empire lost in October 1918, not 1914.